# How to serialize an object that is composed of other custom class in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am new in the topic of serialization. I have seen some demos of serialization of a class in Java and I have tried serialization by myself as well. Now, I don't have any issue with serialization of a class that only contains built-in java types. However, I try to serialize a class that has reference to another custom defined class (composition), it seems like serialization is not happening properly.

Take this code for example:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
   String name, id;
   int age;
   Project assignedProject; // Project type is a custom defined Class

/*
   Constructors, Getters, Setters, Methods and Functions
*/
}

public class Project {
   String projectName;
}
```

Now, If try to serialize an instance of User class and read back from it, then I will get null in `assignedProject` field. What should I do to store the `assignedProject` variable as well.

Comment: The `Project` class also needs to implement `Serializable`, and same goes for any user-defined classes that *it* references.

Comment: Or declare it `transient Project assignedProject;`

Comment: @g.momo The OP said *"What should I do to store the assignedProject variable as well."*  A transient field will not be serialized, by definition.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong you are right.